# I installed php-soap with rpm file on Centos but doesn't work

Tags: apache-2.2, php, centos, soap

I installed php-soap on my Centos server from RPM file. Then I restarted httpd service but doesn't work SOAP client.

When I get:

```
yum list installed
```

php-soap listed here:

```
php.i386                            5.3.6-1.w5                         installed
php-cli.i386                        5.3.6-1.w5                         installed
php-common.i386                     5.3.6-1.w5                         installed
php-devel.i386                      5.3.6-1.w5                         installed
php-gd.i386                         5.3.6-1.w5                         installed
php-imap.i386                       5.3.6-1.w5                         installed
php-mbstring.i386                   5.3.6-1.w5                         installed
php-mysql.i386                      5.3.6-1.w5                         installed
php-pdo.i386                        5.3.6-1.w5                         installed
php-pear.noarch                     1:1.4.9-6.el5                      installed
php-soap.i386                       5.2.17-1.el5.art                   installed
php-xml.i386                        5.3.6-1.w5                         installed
```

There are SOAP options in php.ini file, there is soap.so in extension dir. But doesn't appear any SOAP option on phpinfo page. (Only soap.ini listed in ini files)

What can I do for enable SOAP extension?

Comment: Is there an enabled `extension=soap.so`-entry in your `php.ini`?

Comment: Did the RPM automatically enable the module in your php.ini file?

Comment: Yes in php.ini file extension was enabled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the soap.ini and verify that the line with the *.so file listed isn't commented. In case remove the `;` infront of `extension=...` and restart your webserver `apachectl restart`

**Update**
It seems you installed the php 5.**2** SOAP to a PHP 5.**3** which should not work together. Try install the 5.3.x SOAP.

Comment: ';' already removed in soap.ini

Comment: Updated my answer. Hope this helps.